# Render part of the form via JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for showing transactions (in `index` action). Form consists of two parts: main and additional.

```
<%= form_for transaction, remote: true do |f| %>
  # some form fields (main part)
  <%= link_to 'Show additional', '#', class: 'show_additional' %>
  <%= render 'transaction_additional', transaction: transaction, f: f %>
<% end %>
```

Now link for showing additional part only makes it visible via JS (remove `display: none;` from it). But I don't want to render additional part on a page, and render it only when user click on this link. Because there are a lot of transactions on a page and it takes a lot of time to load a page with additional info of all of them.

I've tried to make it remote and load it with `show` action.

```
<%= form_for transaction, remote: true do |f| %>
  # some form fields (main part)
  <%= link_to 'Show additional', transactions_path(transaction), class: 'show_additional', remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

And in `show.js.erb`

```
$(this).closest('form').append('<%= render 'transaction_additional', transaction: @transaction, f: f %>');
```

It takes `@transaction` from `show` action in controller, but I don't know how to pass `f` variable to `show` action, and get

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x00000109d11258>:0x000001017939a0>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: send the values in locale

Comment: you neither have 'this' nor have 'f' in your show.js.erb, u can put your whole form inside show.js.erb...except the link

Answer (score 0):

Further to Rahul Singh, you don't have the `f` object available in `show.js.erb`, which means you'll have to initialize a new one

I'd do this:

```
#app/views/view/show.js.erb
<%= form_for @transaction do |f| %>
    $("form").append('<%= render 'transaction_additional', transaction: @transaction, f: f %>');
<% end %>
```